# Query case-specific nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a setup like the attached image. **Orange nodes** denotes the **cases** and the **Blue nodes** denotes the **Performers** of various activities within that case.

[image: Case specifics nodes]

I would like to query each case in turn. Within each case, I need to add relationship

```
[:RELATED {value: 1}]
```

from **node<sub>i</sub>** to **node<sub>k</sub>** , for all k that lies in between(nodes whose ID fall between i and j) those pair of Performer nodes (**node<sub>i</sub>**,**node<sub>j</sub>**) such that :
**Name(node<sub>i</sub>)** == **Name( node<sub>j</sub> )** 
and 
  **| ID(node<sub>i</sub>) - ID(node<sub>j</sub>) | >= 2**

**[Example and Expected Output]:**

1. In Case1, since Performer nodes with ID:1 and ID:4 satisfy the criteria, so relationships are added between:

   ```
          Node(ID:1) to Node(ID:2)

          Node(ID:1) to Node(ID:3)
   ```

2. In Case2, Performer nodes with ID:2 and ID:4 satisfy the criteria, so relationships are added between:

   ```
          Node(ID:2) to Node(ID:3)
   ```

3. In Case3, there are two sets of nodes satisfying the criteria,

   a. For Node(ID:1) and Node(ID:4) add relationships from

   ```
          Node(ID:1) to Node(ID:2)

          Node(ID:1) to Node(ID:3)
   ```

   b. For Node(ID:3) and Node(ID:5), add relationship from

   ```
          Node(ID:3) to Node(ID:4)
   ```

Hint needed in formulating CYPHER queries for the above case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case 1, why should there be a rel between `Node(ID:1) to Node(ID:2)`? Not the same name and (2 - 1) == 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned in the question comment, your calculation should be reversed :

```
node j - node i >= 2
```

One point more, for case 3, Following your explanations there should be a third relationship between node 2 and 3

Here is a query I made, you can test it in this neo4j console : http://console.neo4j.org/r/gpfesu

```
MATCH (n:Case) 
MATCH path=(pe)<--(n)-->(pe2)
WHERE pe.name = pe2.name
AND pe2.id - pe.id >= 2
WITH path,n, (pe2.id - pe.id) as length
WITH range(head(nodes(path)).id+1, last(nodes(path)).id-1) as ids,
     n, 
     head(nodes(path)).id as starter,
     length
UNWIND ids as x
MATCH (perf:Performer {id:starter})<--(n)-->(perf2:Performer {id:x})
MERGE (perf)-[:RELATES_TO {value:1, length:length}]->(perf2)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes in the question. Your solution made my day  :)

Comment: In case1(and similarly for others), the relation between Node(ID:1) and Node(ID:2) was because of Node(ID:1) & Node(ID:4) satisfying the criteria. Is it possible to add another property "Length" to :RELATES_TO which will store the difference of IDs of Node(ID:1) and Node(ID:4). So in case1, (A->D) will have Length:3, (A->B) will have Length:3 and (B->A) will have Length:2. Tried to use Length: pe2.id-perf.id, but it says pe2 not defined.

Comment: It is because pe and pe2 are not passed to the rest of the query with WITH. I updated the answer to add the length property on the relationship.