# Add Unique Nodes and relationship between them from Existing Setup in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is in continuation of the problem defined here

[Query case-specific nodes in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711813/query-case-specific-nodes-in-neo4j)

So the situation looks like the image below(please bear with the crappy image)
[image]

The blue links denotes the **[:RELATES_TO]** relationship with the number in black boxes denoting the value of ***Length*** property. Similar values also exists for all such other **[:RELATES_TO]** relationship which is not shown here.

Now I would like to ***find and create unique Nodes based on 'Name' property of Performer Nodes***. Continuing with the example in the link there will be only 4 New Unique Nodes *[A,B,C,D]*. Lets Call them **NewUniqueNodes** with *name as a property*.

Then I would like to query each case in turn. Within each case, I need to query [:RELATES_TO] relationship in ***increasing order of Length property***. For any such pair of nodes **(x,y)** I need to add a relationship **[:FINALRESULT{strength:0}] from NewUniqueNode(Name:x) to NewUniqueNode(name:y)** with strength being updated to **(strength + *value*)**. The ***value*** is the number associated with ***value*** property of **[:RELATES_TO]** for the pair of **nodes(x,y)**.

**[Example and Expected Output]**

In case1, the order of visiting nodes will be

```
Node(ID:3) to Node(ID:4)
Node(ID:1) to Node(ID:2)
Node(ID:1) to Node(ID:3)
```

On processing these nodes, the result would be

```
NewUniqueNode(name:A)-[:FINALRESULT{strength: 1}]-NewUniqueNode(name:D)
NewUniqueNode(name:A)-[:FINALRESULT{strength: 1}]-NewUniqueNode(name:B)
NewUniqueNode(name:B)-[:FINALRESULT{strength: 1}]-NewUniqueNode(name:A)
```

On processing the full set of cases(**case1** + **case2** + **case3**), the result would be something like

```
NewUniqueNode(name:A)-[:FINALRESULT{strength: 1}]-NewUniqueNode(name:D)
NewUniqueNode(name:A)-[:FINALRESULT{strength: 3}]-NewUniqueNode(name:B)
NewUniqueNode(name:B)-[:FINALRESULT{strength: 2}]-NewUniqueNode(name:A)
NewUniqueNode(name:C)-[:FINALRESULT{strength: 1}]-NewUniqueNode(name:B)
NewUniqueNode(name:A)-[:FINALRESULT{strength: 1}]-NewUniqueNode(name:A)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this Neo4j console setup, based on the previous question http://console.neo4j.org/r/vci9yd
I have the following query :

```
MATCH (n:Performer) 
WITH collect(DISTINCT (n.name)) AS names 
UNWIND names as name 
MERGE (nn:NewUniqueNode {name:name}) 
WITH names 
MATCH (c:Case)
MATCH (p1)-[r:RELATES_TO]->(p2)<-[:RELATES]-(c)-[:RELATES]->(p1)
WITH r
ORDER BY r.length
MATCH (nn1:NewUniqueNode {name:startNode(r).name}) 
MATCH (nn2:NewUniqueNode {name:endNode(r).name}) 
MERGE (nn1)-[rf:FINAL_RESULT]->(nn2)
SET rf.strength = CASE WHEN rf.strength IS NULL THEN r.value ELSE rf.strength + r.value END
```

Explanations :

- First we match all performer nodes and collect the distinct name values in the names variable.
- Secondly, we iterate the names with the UNWIND clause, creating a NewUniqueNode for each name in the names collection
- Then we match all cases, within each case we look for the :RELATES_TO relationships that are inside this case and ordering them by the relationship length value
- Then for each relationship found, we match the NewUniqueNode corresponding to the startNode name value, and same for the NewUniqueNode corresponding to the endNode name value
- Lastly we merge the :FINAL RESULT relationship between those two unique nodes, we then set the strength property on the relationship depending of the :RELATES_TO relationship length value, for this part I guess you could do the same with ON CREATE and ON MATCH on the MERGE

Comment: This doesn't quite meet the requirements because I need to traverse the existing graph setup "case wise" and within each case, in increasing order of "Length" property value. It is so because with every change I need to add a fractional value to a variable "normal" which I have defined it as a node containing value property that keeps adding that change.

Comment: i updated the answer, if it does not fit your requirements maybe I'm missing something :)

Comment: This does meet the requirements. I must admit, it took some time to understand the code. Thanks.

Comment: with pleasure. For the future, could you create some neo4j console setups and post the link with the question so we can immediately test the queries on your model. Thanks !

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the input. And well your status "I eat Neo4j for breakfast" is quite fitting your answers :)

Comment: :) I added some explanations, maybe helpful for you or others.