# Keep track of Changes in Neo4j - Achieve functionality like a "flag" variable in standard programming

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Initial setup of the sample database is provided [link to console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=5lcp9x)

There are various cases and within each case, there are performers(with properties id and name). This is the continuation of problems defined [problem statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711813/query-case-specific-nodes-in-neo4j) and [solution to unique node creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725476/add-unique-nodes-and-relationship-between-them-from-existing-setup-in-neo4j)

The solution in the second link is ([credits to Christophe Willemsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662355/christophe-willemsen)
)

```
MATCH (n:Performer) 
WITH collect(DISTINCT (n.name)) AS names 
UNWIND names as name 
MERGE (nn:NewUniqueNode {name:name}) 
WITH names 
MATCH (c:Case)
MATCH (p1)-[r:RELATES_TO]->(p2)<-[:RELATES]-(c)-[:RELATES]->(p1)
WITH r
ORDER BY r.length
MATCH (nn1:NewUniqueNode {name:startNode(r).name}) 
MATCH (nn2:NewUniqueNode {name:endNode(r).name}) 
MERGE (nn1)-[rf:FINAL_RESULT]->(nn2)
SET rf.strength = CASE WHEN rf.strength IS NULL THEN r.value ELSE rf.strength + r.value END
```

This solution achieved what was asked for.

But I need to achieve something like this.

```
foreach (Case.id in the database)
     {
      foreach(distinct value of r.Length)
         {
         //update value property of node normal
         normal.value=normal.value+0.5^(r.Length-2)

         //create new nodes and add the result as their relationship or merge it to existing one
         MATCH (nn1:NewUniqueNode {name:startNode(r).name}) 
         MATCH (nn2:NewUniqueNode {name:endNode(r).name}) 
         MERGE (nn1)-[rf:FINAL_RESULT]->(nn2)

         //
         rf.strength=rf.strength + r.value*0.5^(r.Length-2);
         }
     }
```

The problem is to track the change in the **case** and then the **r.Length** property. How can it be achieved in Cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will not redo the last part, where setting strengths.

One thing though, in your console link, there is only one Normal node, so why do you need to iterate over each case, you can just match distinct relationships lengths.

By the way for the first part :

```
MATCH (n:Case)
MATCH (n)-[:RELATES]->()-[r:RELATES_TO]->()<-[:RELATES]-(n)
WITH collect(DISTINCT (r.length)) AS lengths
MATCH (normal:Normal)
UNWIND lengths AS l
SET normal.value = normal.value +(0.5^l)
RETURN normal.value
```

Explanations :

- Match the cases
- Foreach case, match the RELATES_TO relationships of Performers for that Case
- collect distinct lengths
- Match the Normal node, iterate the the distinct lengths collection and setting the proper value on the normal node